# One of the dist file is always empty after running webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I am new to webpack and have followed the quick start guide to create and process a simple js file from src to dist.  All fine.

However now I am trying to get it to process more than one JS file but have hit a problem I can't find a way around.  The file from the original tutorial still processes fine into dist, however a new JS file I have created does create a file into dist, but it is empty.  The JS is not being minified into the dist.

So when running the below. /dist/scripttwo.js is fine..

HOWEVER, /dist/scriptone.js is always just an empty file.

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
      scriptone: './src/scriptone.js',
      scripttwo: './src/scripttwo.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
};
```

**scriptone.js**

```js
function sayhello() {
  return 'hello again';
}
```

**scripttwo.js**

```js
import _ from 'lodash';

function component() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');

  // Lodash, currently included via a script, is required for this line to work
  element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ');

  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are not exporting or importing anything to `scriptone.js`.

to test:
export `sayhello` from `scriptone.js` add the following to end of file:

```
export defalut sayhello
```

and in `scripttwo.js` import the function and use it inside the file:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import sayhello from './scriptone.js';

function component() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');

  // Lodash, currently included via a script, is required for this line to work
  element.innerHTML = _.join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ') + sayhello();

  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

Answer (score 1):

The code will be there if you use `mode: "development"` configuration.

By default, Webpack uses `production` [mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/), Webpack v4+ will minify and tree shaking your code by default in production mode. The code in `scriptone.js` does nothing, has no [side effects](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free), it's dead code, Webpack will drop it. That's why you get an empty `dist/scriptone.js` bundle file.

Comment: Thanks slideshowp2 .. that game me the missing piece to understanding webpack.. Cheers !